# How to drive a 15 Vdc relay coil from ESP8266 3.3 V logic

Tags: relay, opto-isolator, esp8266

I want to control a series of Zettler AZ2100–1A–15DE relays with an ESP8266 Wemos D1 Mini microcontroller.

I thought I could do this with an optocoupler, so I bought an 8-channel PC817 board [from Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B5D9LCXK) that advertised 3.3 - 5 V control of 3.6-30 V.

I connected it as follows:

[image: wiring diagram]

However, it won't energize the relay coil.

I even tried giving the input 5 V instead of 3.3 V thinking maybe it wasn't in saturation, but it still doesn't work. I then tested the resistance of the output and found that its 5 kΩ at 5 V and 8.6 kΩ at 3.3 V.

I'm assuming that this is the reason the coil on my relay won't energize.

Looking for a recommendation on how to make this work, preferably with a readily available board.

The [data sheet](https://www.onlinecomponents.com/en/datasheet/az21001a15de-10609983/) for the relay:

[image: relay data sheet]

Comment: Requests for product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: You can buy *MOSFET Driver Modules* for the hobbyist market. But, you will get poor specifications (if any), no schematic, and no revision control. I ordered twice and got 2 completely different designs. I am able to adapt them to meet my needs, but it is frustrating.

Comment: You should never connect an inductive load such as a relay to a microprocessor port as it will destroy it. As you found out it will not drive the relay but the inductive flyback is still there. A rule of thumb most ports will drive a max of 20 mA but you need to check the data sheet to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'm assuming that this is the reason the coil on my relay won't
> energize?*

Correct.

Your relay coil needs about 60 mA to activate it according to the data in your question. I would use a MOSFET instead of the board you bought: -

[image]

Pick a MOSFET whose gate-source voltage is low enough for the logic levels your ESP is using. Make sure the MOSFET turns on to an ohm or less when activated and make sure that it is at least 30 volt rated. Don't forget the flyback diode (1N400x will do).

Image from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html) and note that the MOSFET in the picture is "well over the top" for what you need.

Comment: Place the 10K resistor on the port pin not the gate pin. In this configuration it is forming a voltage divider. That is dividing the 3.3V from the port to 3.0V for the gate, this will impact the enhancement of the MOSFET. If you use an avalanche rated MOSFET no flyback diode will be needed.

Comment: @Gil thanks for that and yes, you just can't get the google images that are good these days!!!

Comment: Thanks for direction. Ordered a D1 Mini mosfet shield. https://www.tindie.com/products/mostlyrobots/4-channel-mosfet-shield-for-wemos-d1-mini-esp8266/

Answer (score 1):

The pc817 has two requirements for you. One is the input voltage and forward current. You need to make sure you can provide 20mA at 1.4V. The esp may not be able to produce 20mA at your gpio. And you would need a resistor to drop the rest of the voltage or it can burn out.

And Two, the max collector current is 30mA. Half of what you need to power your relay. Trying to drive a larger load can burn it out.

In ideal situation, the pc817 is just not built for the job you want it to do.

A direct relay driver with a standard npn small signal transistor like the 2n2222 or 2n3904 would be enough. Any logic level mosfet would also work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want opto-isolation between the 15V supply and noisy relay and the 3.3V supply (and ground) you can use the PC817 as follows (R4 should be open, it's just there to keep LTspice happy). R5 represents the relay coil resistance (I didn't model the inductance, but the diode is there to deal with it):

[image]